# Visual Studio 2022 not working for Azure Functions

Tags: azure-functions, visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-mac, visual-studio-macros

I can't seem to get Azure functions running for Visual Studio 2022 for mac.

I am able to run the functions ok in Visual Studio Code.

The functions come up ok in the terminal for Visual Studio 2022, but when I invoke the function I get this error:

An unhandled host error has occurred.
[2022-10-03T00:50:25.613Z] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: 'yourFunctionName' can't be invoked from Azure WebJobs SDK. Is it missing Azure WebJobs SDK attributes?.

Tried uninstalling and reinstalling but no luck

Comment: Trying to debug my Function app, I'm getting an error that says "Cannot execute "../bin/Debug/net6.0/functions.exe".  how did you get past this?

Answer (score 0):

I reintalled visual studio.
I installed .net core and the .net tools.

It still was not working.

Then I cleaned the project and it started working.